# one to one flash video chat issue

Tags: wordpress, flash, video, red5, buddypress

I am using cometchat chat plugin in my website.
For one to one video chat, to work in all major browsers I needed to configure video chat with RED 5 as suggested by the cometchat support team.

After configured with RED 5 server I have encountered following two serious problems when trying to use the video chat function.

1. The first is after the video chat window screen finished loading, many times the video chat does not work, only displaying a blank screen. The bottom blue buttons always load correctly but often the video chat screen remains blank.
2. The second major issue is when the video chat does load correctly I face a lot of lag in both the audio and video. I don’t know the reason why it’s happening.

Please help me to resolve both these critical issues.
 
My current configuration is as follows:
**cometchat:**
cometchat Version: 5.6.0
cometchat Installation: BuddyPress (Wordpress)

**Server:**
Processor:  Intel Xeon(R) CPU E3 -1265L V2 @ 2.50GHz
Total Number of Processors: 8
RAM: 8GB
Hard Disk: RAID-1 Drives
Bandwidth: 20TB
Hosting Service Provider: Hostgator
Server Type: Dedicated Linux Server

**PHP:**
PHP Version: 5.4.43
memory_limit: 512MB

Comment: I think they have webRTC option. You should use that.

Comment: Which red5 version are you using?

Comment: @alecsmart Thanks.one to one video chat must be work on all browsers thats why I configured with RED 5. webRTC is not working in Safari,IE8,IE9.

Comment: @PaulGregoire I installed RED5 version 1.0.0

Comment: Red5 1.0 was released over 3 years ago, it is out-dated at this time. I would suggest communicating with the cometchat people to get an updated version that works with Red5 1.0.5 and move on from there. Lastly, lag is not normally a server issue specifically but its most likely a condition caused by the network in between the publisher / subscriber.

Comment: @PaulGregoire Thanks for update.I told cometchat to help on this issue,they replied they are now no longer support on RED5 video chat option.I don't know why they provided same option in latest cometchat version 5.6 if they do not support RED5 video chat option.Will it help if i upgrade RED5 server to latest version to resolve the issue?

Comment: You should upgrade to latest version of RED5.